# pulling hashes from system/sam files after windows anniversary update

Tags: windows-10, passwords, kali-linux, password-recovery

Recently I got locked out from my admin account on my acer nitro v laptop running windows 10

I managed to get a kali usb disk but I discovered samdump no longer extracts hashes properly(it returns the hashes as if the passwords were all blanks) on windows 10 past its anniversary update

I think I can copy files into the normal windows session,  so if there is an online site I can upload the files to that would be great

I cant download/install anything without my admin password

Answer (score 1):

If you can get command prompt access to the file system, make a copy of c:\windows\system32\ultiman.exe and copy cmd.exe to ultiman.exe. Kali should get you to the file system, but so can a Windows boot CD.

Then you boot up your machine into regular Windows and at the logon screen hit the accessibility icon in the lower right. It should give you a command prompt running as system.

Then you can enable or create a local administrator account and/or reset the password.

I tried this recently on 1803 and it still works.

Comment: Here is a youtube video showing that process. Adding as a comment since this link may not be around as long as this post. https://youtu.be/oX3-WGLI7iI